# Confidence interval for $\theta$ when $X_i$'s are i.i.d $N(\theta,\theta)$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, confidence-interval

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. r.v. with $N(\theta,\theta)$

I calculated $$E[\bar{X_n}] = \theta$$ $$Var[\bar{X_n}] = \theta/n$$

And want to construct a confidence interval $I_{\theta}$ that is centered around $\bar{X_n}$ such that $\theta \in P(I_{\theta}) = 0.9$ for all n, where $q_{\alpha/2}=q_{0.05}=1.6448$

I am using the general formula: $$\bar{X} \pm Z \frac{s}{\sqrt(n)} = \bar{X_n} \pm 1.6448 \frac{\sqrt{Var[\bar{X_n}]}}{\sqrt(n)} = \bar{X} \pm 1.6448 \frac{\sqrt{\theta}/\sqrt(n)}{\sqrt(n)} = \bar{X} \pm 1.6448 \frac{\sqrt{\theta}}{n}$$

But it seems I am getting it wrong here. Any input would be appreciated. It seems as there is a simple solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statistic to be used is, as usual,

$\bar{X}_n\sim N(\theta;\frac{\theta}{n})$

The pivotal quantity is the following

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
\frac{\bar{X}_n-\theta}{\sqrt{\theta}}\sqrt{n}\sim \Phi
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

So you can find your Confidence interval solving this double inequality with respect to $\theta$

$$-1.64 \leq \frac{\bar{X}_n-\theta}{\sqrt{\theta}}\sqrt{n} \leq 1.64$$

this lead to the exact solution:

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\bar{X}_n+\frac{1.64^2}{2n} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{1.64^2}{2n})^2+ \bar{X}_n \frac{1.64^2}{n} }
\qquad  (2)
}
$$

If you want to find an approx solution, in a very easy way, you can substitute $\sqrt{\theta}$ with its estimation, $\sqrt{\bar{X}_n}$ and you immediately find the following CI from (1)

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\bar{X}_n \pm 1.64 \sqrt{ \frac{\bar{X}_n}{n}}
\qquad  (3)
}
$$

So my conclusion is the following:

*If you are interested in finding a CI of $\theta$ centered around $\bar{X}_n$ the only alternative is to calculate an approximate Interval.*

**Calculations from (1) to  (2)**

$-z<\frac{ \bar{X}-\theta}{\sqrt{\theta}}\sqrt{n}<z$

$( \bar{X}-\theta)^2<\frac{z^2\theta}{n}$

$\bar{X}^2-2\bar{X}\theta+\theta^2-\frac{z^2\theta}{n}<0$

$\theta^2 -\theta(2\bar{X}+\frac{z^2}{n})+\bar{X}^2<0   $

$\theta=\frac{2\bar{X}+\frac{z^2}{n}\pm\sqrt{4\bar{X}^2+\frac{z^4}{n^2}+\frac{4\bar{X}z^2   } {n}    -4\bar{X}^2 }}{2}  $

$\theta=\bar{X}+\frac{z^2}{2n}\pm\sqrt{(\frac{z^2}{2n})^2+\frac{\bar{X}z^2   } {n} } $

1) the notation $\theta=a\pm b$ is a standard notation used in Confidence Intervals. [See here for an example](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/confint.htm). Anyway it is just a problem of notation.

2) On the countrary this, in effect, it is a problem. At a first sight I would have solved the exercise with my formula 2) that is a correct

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\bar{X}_n+\frac{z^2}{2n} - \sqrt{(\frac{z^2}{2n})^2+ \bar{X}_n \frac{z^2}{n} }< \theta<\bar{X}_n+\frac{z^2}{2n} + \sqrt{(\frac{z^2}{2n})^2+ \bar{X}_n \frac{z^2}{n} }
\qquad  (2)
}
$$

Note that, for your happiness, I avoided to use the previous notation and I substituted 1.64 with $z$, indicating a general percentile of the Gaussian. (let me avoid to indicate $z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ and $z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}$ to simplify the notation)

As formula 3) is concerned, I tried to find a CI that was symmetric around $\bar{X}_n$ as requested in the exercise but your observation is absolutely correct: it is a standard way to proceed in other situation but with a $N(\theta;\theta)$ we must pay more attention. Anyway, before answering, I did some simulations and the two formulas (2) and (3) give more or less the same numerical result when $n \rightarrow \infty$

In conclusion: my formula (2) is absolutely correct; (3) works, I do not know why but it works... :)

Comment: Thanks, I see now that using the plug-in we get the example. I also would like to get the nonasymptotic CI by solving the bounds of $I_n$ for $\theta$.

I use the relationship $$ |\hat{\theta}-\theta| \leq \theta * \frac{q_{0.05}}{\sqrt(n)}$$

Where I get $$|\frac{\bar{X_n}-\theta}{\sqrt(Var(\bar{X_n}}| \leq q_{0.05}$$

and $$(\theta-\bar{X_n})^2 \leq q_{0..05}^2 * \frac{\theta}{n}$$

Am i on the right path here? Because when I solve the quadratic equation (after setting $\leq 0$) I get a very long expression, which seems incorrect.. Struggling a bit on this

Comment: It is very easy...set the quadratic equation $\leq 0$, realize that it is verified in the interval between the 2 roots....do simple calculations, simplify what you can and you will get the solution I posted in (2) (I had five minutes calculation, not more)

Comment: I have solved the quadratic equasion and got the formula you provided in (2), I am a bit rusty on these algebraic calculations, so it takes me more time and effort, unfortunately. The upper bound seems to be different though, not just replacing $-$ with $+$ before the square root, but I can't see why this should be the case. Is it not the square root responsible for being able to give 2 answers for the bounds?

Comment: I edited my answer with the detailed calculations. As you can see,  they are only 5 simply algebraic passages.  I hope this helps.

Comment: How did you get an equality for $\theta$ while solving from an inequality? Why $1.64$? And why estimate $\theta$ with $\overline X_n$?

Comment: 1) It is not an equality. It is an inequality but written in the following way

$\hat{\theta}=a \pm b$ meaning $[a-b \leq \hat{\theta} \leq a+b]$


2) 1.64 is the 95° quantile of the Gaussian, requested in the exercise


3) Observe that the variable $Q=\frac{\bar{X}_n-\theta}{\sqrt{\theta}}\sqrt{n}\sim \Phi$.
$Q$ depends on $\theta$ but its Law doesn't: this means that $Q$ is a ***"Pivotal Quantity"*** and this fact allows me to find a CI based on $\bar{X}_n$

Comment: Errata Corrige: substitute the word "quantile" with "percentile"

Comment: (Use @ while replying otherwise we don't get notified) I don't understand how something like $\theta=a\pm b$ is supposed to indicate $a-b \leq \theta \leq a+b$. I am aware of the pivotal quantity but if I am not mistaken, replacing $\sqrt\theta$ by $\sqrt{\overline X_n}$ to get your Wald type interval $(3)$ requires $\overline X_n$ to be an efficient estimator or a root of the likelihood equation.